# Cancel a TPL task from within a TaskScheduler

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to create a `TaskScheduler` that runs all tasks sequentially, but will only ever 'complete' the most recently scheduled task. For example if I use it to schedule task A, then before it finishes schedule tasks B and C, I want only C to be considered successful. A can continue its work, but should be considered 'cancelled' at completion, and B should marked cancelled before it even begins.

I've already got existing code that executes delegates sequentially on the thread pool, and manages the idea of having at most 2 queued tasks - one which is currently executing and one which is next. The missing part is being able to set the result state of the tasks to cancelled

Unfortunately it seems that from within a `TaskScheduler`, you actually get very little access to the state of a `Task`, or any `CancellationToken`.

I've tried to get around this by keeping track of the last-queued task, and when coming to execute a task, throwing a `TaskCancelledException` if it is not equal to the last-queued task, but that doesn't seem to work. I guess this is because the exception is not thrown inside the task's delegate, and all the 'magic' is actually handled inside `TryExecuteTask()`.

Here's what I've got:

```
public class CurrentPendingTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
        {
        private readonly ThreadSafeCurrentPendingQueueProcessor<Task> _Processor;
        private Task _LastTask;

        public CurrentPendingTaskScheduler()
            {
            _Processor = new ThreadSafeCurrentPendingQueueProcessor<Task>();
            _Processor.Process += _Processor_Process;
            }

        private void _Processor_Process(Task obj)
            {
            // If there's a newer task already, cancel this one before starting
            if (obj != _LastTask)
                throw new TaskCanceledException(obj);

            TryExecuteTask(obj);

            // If a newer task was added whilst we worked, cancel this one
            if (obj != _LastTask)
                throw new TaskCanceledException(obj);
            }

        protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
            {
            _LastTask = task;
            _Processor.Enqueue(task);
            }

        protected override Boolean TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
            {
            return false;
            }

        protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
            {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

The `ThreadSafeCurrentPendingQueueProcessor<>` class is a helper which calls back via an event in order to process enqueued items on a single background thread, allowing only one active item and one pending item.

If the 'last task' has changed before the processor callback, the exception just prevents the task from running at all (but doesn't affect its state). If the callback does get to run but the 'last task' has changed during the meantime, the exception is thrown much too late, already after any continuations have been started.

Also I'm not sure at all for the reason for this, but the very first time the scheduler is used (I schedule one task for every UI element click), `QueueTask` is called once, with the new task. However for every subsequent scheduling, it's called twice. This messes things up even further, as `_LastTask` gets overwritten.

I feel like `TaskCompletionSource<>` might be of some use, but can't quite see how.

Is it possible to implement a `TaskScheduler` that works as described? I'm aware that I could achieve this behaviour outside the scheduler, at the point where I create my tasks, but I need to use this in many places and am trying to make life easier by having it in a reusable scheduler.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. The job of `TaskScheduler` is to decide when and where will a `Task` execute, but not what its result will be.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a helper class that takes an input operation, starting it, and cancelling the existing one, and overwriting its internal variable. As you cant perform a `Cancel()` explicitly and directly on a `Task<T>`, you will need to keep your own `TaskCancellationSource` handy. If you want to provide an external token, you can combine them with `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(...)` If you need to keep an eye on the result, that would make a good opportunity for TaskCompletionSource.

```
public class OverwriteTaskHandler<T>
{
    private Task<T> _task;
    private TaskCompletionSource<T> _tcs;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public OverwriteTaskHandler(Func<T> operation)
    {
        _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        TryPushTask(operation);
    }

    public bool TryPushTask(Func<T> operation)
    {
        if (_tcs.Task.IsCompleted)
            return false;   //It would be unsafe to use this instance as it is already "finished"
        _cts.Cancel();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _task = Task.Run(operation, _cts.Token);
        _task.ContinueWith(task => _tcs.SetResult(task.Result));
        return true;
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }

    public Task<T> WrappedTask { get { return _tcs.Task; } }
}
```

**Discalimer:** I haven't tested this, so just double check!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK TaskScheduler can't be used to make this work. You really need something else. For example, you could write yourself a helper class with the following usage:

```
static CurrentPendingTaskContext ctx = ...;

async Task MyAsyncFunc() {
 await ctx.RegisterAndMaybeCancel();
 try {
  //rest of method
 }
 finally {
  ctx.NotifyCompletion();
 }
}
```

`RegisterAndMaybeCancel` would wait until the currently running task is done. It would throw a cancellation exception if this particular task has been superseded by another one.

I don't have time right now to implement that class (although it's tempting). But I think this syntax pattern is simple enough that you can use it in many places.

You can also use the `IDisposable` pattern for this to get rid of the finally:

```
async Task MyAsyncFunc() {
 using (await ctx.RegisterAndMaybeCancel())
 {
      //rest of method
 }
}
```